# ruby Logger formatter change message only

Tags: ruby, logging

I want to change only the `msg` part of the default_formatter in [Ruby 1.9.3 Logger](https://github.com/ruby/ruby/blob/23ccbdf52188b78427f41d75b1a4b81959ac9876/lib/logger.rb#L490-L531).
How can I do this?

I know that I can do

```
logger.formatter = proc do |severity, datetime, progname, msg|
   "[mymessage] #{msg}\n"
end
```

but then I lose the other default formatting of `severity, datetime, progname`.

Ideally I'd like to just do `msg = "[mymessage] " + msg` and then execute the default formatter with this new `msg`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on the [example in documentation](http://ruby-doc.org/stdlib-2.1.0/libdoc/logger/rdoc/Logger.html), one can do the following:

```
require 'logger'
logger = Logger.new(STDOUT)

original_formatter = Logger::Formatter.new
logger.formatter = proc { |severity, datetime, progname, msg|
  original_formatter.call(severity, datetime, progname, "[mymessage] #{msg}\n")
}

logger.debug("I am a debug msg")
logger.info("I am an info msg")
```

Output of program:

```
D, [2016-01-13T12:45:47.354261 #11512] DEBUG -- : [mymessage] I am a debug msg

I, [2016-01-13T12:45:47.354261 #11512]  INFO -- : [mymessage] I am an info msg
```